# Multithreaded console application: Pause on keypress without busy waiting

Tags: multithreading, c++11, keypress, busy-waiting

I am writing a multithreaded console application in C++11. I would love for it to be OS independent, but I am on a linux machine.

I want to be able to pause threads upon a keypress, but for the program to be allowed to finish and exit without any keypresses as well. Currently my pseudocode for my main thread is the following.

```
while other threads are executing
  sleep for 1 second
  if keypress
    *do stuff*
  end if
end while
```

So it's something like a busywait. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score -3):

One way to accomplish it (also in a cross-platform manner) is to use libSDL's, [SDL_KeyboardEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_KeyboardEvent).

Comment: Can you flesh this out a little more? How does one use this to wake up a thread?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12229849)

Comment: @IgorIvancha: Sorry if I'm being dense, but I fail to see how the link answers the question. How does one use this to wake up a sleeping thread?